# Selecting data from two tables without joining

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the deal:

Table A has columns A1 and A2

Table B has columns B1,B2,B3

Now i want to select data from columns A1 and B1 (without join), and the condition is:-

B3='someword' and A2=B2

If there is no need of printing B1, I would have written the query(without join) as:

```
select A1 from A where A2 in (select B2 from B where B3='someword');
```

But i need to print both A1 and B1, So is it possible to do that without using join and using 'IN'???

Comment: Why can't you use a join?

Comment: i can use join, but what if the tables are way too bigggg!!!!!!

Comment: no, not any homework it is, i just got a database format of dictionary after a lot of googling,i want to make a dictionary app myself.I asked the question in this context.

Comment: `IN` will be even worse than `JOIN`  if the tables are large!

Comment: I just wanted to know, if it's possible or not.

Comment: But how come IN makes it worse??

Comment: @DarrenDavies PEOPLE ALL OVER THE WOOOOOOOOOOOOORLD, JOIN TABLES, WE'LL START A LOVE TRAIN, LOVE TRAIN http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w6p4gYHd-E

Comment: i was expecting something magical like this: making use of already selected B2 in - select A1 from A where A2 in (select B1,B2 from B where B3='someword');
I know it sounds silly, but i expected there might be privision for doing that.unfortunately, it seems there is no such thing.thank you

Comment: The query optimizer is often smarter than users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say you need to restrict the ouput to where  A2=B2

YOU ARE SPECIFYING a JOIN.

calling it something else does not change what it was... To paraphrase Willie,

"A Join by any other name is still a Join"

Seriously,  a "Join" is *not* the name, nor the word nor even the syntax in a query used to apply it,  it is the logical predicate or restriction, or filter, that is based on values from two different tables.  If you need to restrict the output to where Table1.A2  equals Table2,B2, then you have a Join

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this without `JOIN` effectively or in other words you can use `inserted select` maybe but this operation is much more slower like `JOIN`, `JOIN` is the best choice and programmatically and database written. Your potencial future client would not so happy when you would sell him slow IS.

Comment: i would have set yours too, but stackoverflow is not letting me do that...thank you, anyway.